# I can't play mp4 videos in Parole version 0.9.1 (codec missing), Xubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: xubuntu, video, codecs, mp4

I can't fix Parole media player to play mp4 videos! I search and research on internet but none of suggestions worked for me. I installed latest version via Ubuntu repositories but no avail to play video, I got the following message :

"Required plugin could not be found"

"Parole Media Player requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: H.264 (Main Profile) decoder"

Before upgrading to version 0.9.1 I had version 0.8.1, also not playing videos.
What can I do to fix this? I have all dependencies installed (for parole, for gstreamer, and so on). Attached screenshot of parole. Thanks, Vladi
[image: Parole missing codec]

Comment: Try with [parole 1.0.0](https://mail.xfce.org/pipermail/xfce-announce/2018-March/000585.html).

Comment: @Mitch Not good idea, requires GTK3 version 3.20 or superior, I have version 3.18.9 and to upgrade GTK 3 to that version will break my system. NEED other solution.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on Fedora and fixed it by installing `gstreamer1-plugin-openh264`. I'm not sure if the package name is the same on Ubuntu though.

Comment: There is no package with this name in Ubuntu repositories.  Can you determine how to solve the issue in Ubuntu (or find out the corresponding package name) and edit your answer accordingly?  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic